# System.Decimal rounds on assignment

Tags: .net, clr, decimal, rounding

can anyone explain why I am getting the following results?

```
Dim badDecimal As Decimal = 54.50327999999999 
Dim expectedDecimal As Decimal = CDec("54.50327999999999")
```

badDecimal = 54.50328D, while expectedDecimal = 54.50327999999999D. My understanding is that badDecimal should contain the value of expectedDecimal (the fact that expectedDecimal can hold the correct value suggests that the Decimal type has the precision to hold the value).

thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: I don't know all that much VB.NET, but in C# you need to suffix a number with the M character to denote that it is a decimal number, otherwise it is a double. So, do you need to do the same in VB, so that in effect, the first line there is assigning a double value (the double interpretation of 54.50327999999999) to a decimal, and thus lost the precision already at compile-time?

Comment: you beautiful man, that was indeed the problem! I kind of assumed as i was declaring the var to be of Decimal type, the compiler would infer that. Care to re-post that answer so i can mark it as the soloution?

Comment: Reposted comment as answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606610/system-decimal-rounds-on-assignment/2606685#2606685

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this page: [Decimal Data Type (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx), you need to suffix decimal literal values with the uppercase character `D`, otherwise the compiler will try to compile it as an appropriate, but different, numeric type, like [Integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2(v=VS.90).aspx), [Long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15(v=VS.90).aspx), [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx), etc. depending on the constant value being used.

In your case, the code basically looks like this to the compiler:

```
Dim badDecimal As Decimal = (constant of type System.Double)
```

And thus already at compile-time, the constant value lost its precision.

Simply change the code to this:

```
Dim badDecimal As Decimal = 54.50327999999999D
                                             ^
                                             +-- add this
```

and it should work as expected.

However, I would be weary of expecting the two variables to compare identical, there's enough questions on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) about "problems" with floating point types to at least make me tell you that you might have a minor difference in the Nth decimal, tiny enough to not make it to the display or the debugger, but enough to make the two variables compare different.

So keep that in mind if you intend to compare them, the typical way is to subtract one value from the other, take its absolute value, and compare that against some miniscule value to say "I accept a different this big, but not bigger".

ie. like this:

```
If Math.Abs(badDecimal - expectedDecimal) < 0.000001 Then
```

instead of this:

```
If badDecimal = expectedDecimal Then
```

Comment: My apologies in advance if the "If Math.Abs..." statement doesn't compile out of the box, as I said in my original comment, I'm not all that fluent in VB.NET :)

Comment: I'm not sure `decimal` counts as a floating point type for the usual floating point != real number issues. (But you are right with the problem here: assigning a double to a decimal causes rounding.)

Comment: Decimal does not have infinite precision, so the same rules apply, it just has a more precise [sic] definition of its precision